# MouseHover Event on DataGridView - Index Out of Range

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I have a [winforms](/questions/tagged/winforms) application with a `DataGridView`, and have been trying to set up a `MouseHover` event which provides some more detailed information about the cell being hovered over.

My code is as follows:

```
private void dataCaseHistory_MouseHover(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        DataGridView grid = (DataGridView)sender;
        Point clientPos = grid.PointToClient(Control.MousePosition);
        DataGridViewCell cell = (DataGridViewCell)grid[clientPos.X, clientPos.Y];
        int cellRow = cell.RowIndex;
        int cellColumn = cell.ColumnIndex;

        DataTable table = (DataTable)dataCaseHistory.DataSource;
        int docColumn = table.Columns.IndexOf("Doc");
        if (cellColumn == docColumn)
        {
            var varBundleID = table.Rows[cellRow]["BundleID"];
            if (varBundleID != DBNull.Value && varBundleID != null)
            {
                int bundleID = (int)varBundleID;
                cBundle bundle = new cBundle(bundleID);
                string header = "Bundle: '" + bundle.Name + "'";
                string body = "";
                foreach (DataRow row in bundle.DocumentBundle.Rows)
                {
                    int docID = (int)row["DocumentID"];
                    cDocument doc = new cDocument(docID);
                    body += doc.DocumentName + Environment.NewLine;
                }
                MessageBox.Show(body, header);
            }
            else
            {
                var varDocID = table.Rows[cellRow]["DocID"];
                if (varDocID != DBNull.Value && varDocID != null)
                {
                    int docID = (int)varDocID;
                    cDocument doc = new cDocument(docID);
                    string header = "Document";
                    string body = doc.DocumentName;
                    MessageBox.Show(body, header);
                }
            }
        }                
    }
    catch (Exception eX)
    {
        string eM = "Error occurred when Single Clicking a Document link in the History tab";
        aError err = new aError(eX, eM);
        MessageBox.Show(eX.Message, eM);
    }
}
```

But I get an index out of range error as soon as the form loads and whenever I move my mouse.  I've never used this event before, so I'd be most appreciative if someone could point out where I am going wrong.

Answer (score 2):

The Item[] property which you access in this line of code:

```
    DataGridViewCell cell = (DataGridViewCell)grid[clientPos.X, clientPos.Y];
```

is indexed by row and column not by screen coordinates, so your screen coordinates are probably much higher than the number of rows or columns in your grid, therefore causing IndexOutOfRange exception.

You should get the cell using the HitTestInfo class:

```
    MouseEventArgs args = (MouseEventaArgs) e;  
    DataGridView.HitTestInfo hitTest = this.grid.HitTest(args.X, args.Y);
    if (hitTest.Type == DataGridViewHitTestType.Cell)
    {
         DataGridViewCell cell = (DataGridViewCell)this.Grid[hitText.ColumnIndex, hitTest.RowIndex];
         // execute business logic here
    }
```

Comment: You should also check that `hitTest.Type == DataGridViewHitTestType.Cell`.